# J2SSH Maverick behavior on network glitch

Tags: j2ssh

We are using Maverick to use SSH to launch shell scripts when building servers. Some of these scripts can take a long while to run (over 30 minutes). Sometimes the Maverick call returns early (with rc=1), but the script at the other end keeps running. What could be causing this early return? A network glitch? Is it expected behavior that the script keeps running? As far as I can tell this not explicitly coded in our code (no `nohup`, no `&` for background...).

Comment: If you are receiving an exit code from the process then the SSH server does at least think the process has terminated. Maverick would not provide you with an exit code if the server does not provide one (the value would be different). Ideally, to diagnose this properly we would need to see DEBUG log output to understand what is happening. Do you have connection timeouts set? I assume the process does not output anything and so the connection could look idle to one or both sides of the connection.

Comment: No timeouts set AFAIK. Will see if I can get some debug output.